# How to click on toggle button using VBA Selenium

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Can sameone help me to click on a toogle button using VBA/Selenium:

HTML:

```html
<img name="toggleFiltro" src="https://curyempreendimentos.sienge.com.br/sienge/imagens/base/toggleDown.png" onmouseover="IH_toggleOver(this)" onmouseout="IH_toggleOut(this)" style="cursor: pointer;">
```

Here is what I tried so far, but it's not displaying the information:

```
ChromoLink.FindElementByXPath("//img[@src='https://curyempreendimentos.sienge.com.br/sienge/imagens/base/toggleDown.png']").Click
```

and this one:

```
ChromoLink.FindElementByXPath("//*[@name=""divFiltro""]").Click
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it:

```
ChromoLink.FindElementByXPath("//*@id=""holderConteudo2""]/form/div[9]/span/img").Click
```